# From which SDK Visual Studio 2022 builds .Net Framework 4.8 Project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, devops

I have a old ASP.Net codebase that was build with .Net framework 4.8.

The solution build fine from visual studio 2022 on local machine, But in our DevOps VM, I have installed `.NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack Offline` as available in this Microsoft [URL](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/thank-you/net48-developer-pack-offline-installer)

From there if we run `dotnet build` command, the DLLs are generated successfully, but they are throwing various runtime errors. Surprisingly, if we replace those DLLs with the one generated from Visual Studio 2022 then everything works fine.

My guess is that due to SDK version mismatch the DevOps-generated-DLLs are incompatible with the rest of the 3rd party packages.

So I wanted to check which version of .NET SDK is used by Visual Studio 2022 to build .NET 4.8 Apps.

I tried to run this command in windows CMD

```
> dotnet sdk check
```

Here is the output:

```
.NET SDKs:

Version      Status
----------------------------------------
3.1.426      .NET 3.1 is out of support.
6.0.100      Patch 6.0.127 is available.
6.0.127      Up to date.
```

It does not even list the Classic .NET framework SDKs, then I am confused how Visual Studio even builds .NET 4.8 Apps?

From where I can check which SDK is used by Visual Studio 2022 to build .NET 4.8 Apps?

Comment: .NET Framework doesn't use any .NET Core SDKs. .NET 5 and later are .NET *Core* versions, not .NET Framework. `dotnet` commands aren't used with .NET Framework at all.

Comment: For ASP.NET over .NET framework you often need to have VS do the build: you need VS on the CI build server and use it to do the build.

Comment: There's no need for Visual Studio itself. The [.NET Framework SDK Developer Pack](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net481) can be downloaded and installed separately.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [MSBuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2022)